# Does Your Animal Companion Only Get 2 Skill Proficiencies or Does It Get More?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, unearthed-arcana

In Unearthed Arcana, Revised Ranger it has a section in the beast conclave archetype that tells you to pick two skills for your animal companion to be proficient in.

> Your animal companion gains proficiency in two skills of your choice.
>   -Unearthed Arcana, Revised Ranger.

Does that mean that if the animal is proficient in skills before, does becoming your companion clean the slate and you get to choose two skills for it to be proficient in or does it mean that you get two additional skills to be proficient in?

Let's say that you get a wolf as an animal companion and a wolf is naturally proficient in stealth and perception. Does that mean that when the wolf becomes your animal companion that it then gets to keep the original skill proficiencies and then add two more or that it has no skills that it is proficent in and you get to choose it's only two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes** They are additional. It specifically says *gain*, so if an animal is already proficient with something, it *gains* or *adds* the newly chosen proficiencies to its stats. You just teach the old <s>dog</s>wolf a new trick or two, aye?